# regex to get "words" containing letters and (numbers/certain special), but not only numbers

Tags: python, regex

In short: I'd like to match any "word" (contiguous set of characters separated by whitespace) containing 1 letter and at least 1 of (numbers/certain special characters). These "words" can appear anywhere in a sentence.

Trying this in `python` using `re` So far, as a pattern, I have:

`\w*[\d@]\w*`

Which works, for the most part; however, I don't want to have "words" that are only numbers/special. Ex:

Should match:

```
h1DF346
123FE453
3f3g6hj7j5v3
hasdf@asdf
r3
r@
```

Should not match:

```
555555
@
hello
onlyletters
```

Having trouble excluding the first two under "should not match". Feel like there's something simple I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: When you say _"word" (contiguous set of characters) _ and use `\w` it will also contain digits. As `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Also clarify which _certain special characters_ ?

Comment: for example, the @ in the pattern i posted. There should be at least 1 letter, AND (1 number or 1 @#) -- specials characters i just added the @ example for now for simplicity here -- i dont know which ones fully I'll need yet but seeing the pattern with @ should suffice

Comment: Are these "words" the only thing in a line or can they occur everywhere?

Comment: can occur anywhere on the line. like: "hello 123test world" should just get 123test

Comment: what will be the regex to get words with only alphabet characters appended with ':' at the end? like `key:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `|` or operator like this:

```
([A-Za-z]+[\d@]+[\w@]*|[\d@]+[A-Za-z]+[\w@]*)
```

meaning you want:

- letters followed by numbers@ followed by any combination,
- or numbers@ followed by letters followed by any combination

[Check the regex101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lBcGvU/1)

consider using non-capturing groups `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` if you are working with groups in other parts of your regular expression.

Comment: It takes less steps than Rahul answer, and more steps than @Jan 's answer that doesn't work :P

Comment: @Jan still failing: Given "Jan" matches "an" which shouldn't ;)

Comment: @Jan matches "123@" which shouldn't :) I would be really surprised (and eager to know how to do it) if a 10 times improvement can be made above my answer because the or'ed regexes should fail on the first character...

Comment: The solution imo is to make the the first alternatives ***possessive***, see this example which matches all of the desired words but leaves the rest (338 steps are needed): https://regex101.com/r/lBcGvU/5

Answer (score 1):

If you merely change the * (match 0 or more) for + (match 1 or more), you can hit everything correctly.

\w+[\d@]\w+

Except for the 5555...  Is there any further pattern to the distribution of letters and numbers that you can distinguish?  Can you handle it by replacing a \w by a requirement for at least one letter before or after the [\d@]?

Comment: It will not match "r@" which should match

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead assertions like this.

**Regex:** `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#\d])[a-zA-Z\d@#]+`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` tests if `something or not` is followed by one letter.
- `(?=.*[@#\d])` tests if `something or not` is followed by one character from given character class.
- `[a-zA-Z\d@#]+` matches one or more characters from given character class.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWTNJK/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

While you have your answer, you could still improve the velocity of the accepted regex:

```
(?=\d++[A-Za-z]+[\w@]+|[a-zA-Z]++[\w@]+)[\w@]{2,}
```

You'll need the newer `regex` module here:

```
import regex as re

string = "h1DF346 123FE453 3f3g6hj7j5v3 hasdf@asdf r3 r@ 555555 @ hello onlyletters"
rx = re.compile(r'(?=\d++[A-Za-z]+[\w@]+|[a-zA-Z]++[\w@]+)[\w@]{2,}')
print(rx.findall(string))
# ['h1DF346', '123FE453', '3f3g6hj7j5v3', 'hasdf@asdf', 'r3', 'r@']
```

Highjacking @Roberto's demo, you'll have a [**significant reduction**](https://regex101.com/r/lBcGvU/5) in steps needed to find matches (>7000 vs 338, ~20 times).

Comment: Interesting! Haven't heard of SKIP/FAIL before and definitely want to look more into that. This example (however) appears to also match any word starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: It would match "@@@" which shouldn't

Comment: @NikT: Adjusted, it does not anymore (still this was no requirement in your original post).

Comment: Given "NikT" matches "ikT" which shouldn't :P

Comment: It matches "123@" which shouldn't ;)

Comment: @Jan what will be the regex to get words with only alphabet characters appended with ':' at the end? like `key:`