# Get the first string with numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset that contains a pandas dataframe which like this

```
CC| WW| 765432 | yqma

HH| C1232| uman

na| NN| 7830 | man| nnn

NN| CC| C1233 | A1000

NN| C12333 | A10

NN| 12333 | A100
```

I need only the first value that contains a number. Sometimes there is a number with the string and sometimes there are not in the same position.

How can I do this?

Comment: `|` means columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all values are in one column use:

Thank you @moys for solution:

```
df['first'] = df['col'].str.findall(r'(?:[a-zA-Z]?)[\d]+').str[0]
```

Or solution by changed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187235):

```
pat = r'[A-Za-z]+[\d]+[\w]*|[\d]+[A-Za-z]+[\w]*|[\d]+[\w]*'
df['first'] = df['col'].str.findall(pat).str[0]
```

Or solution form @Chris A, thank you:

```
df['first'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(\S*?\d+)')
```

---

```
print (df)
                       col   first
0    CC| WW| 765432 | yqma  765432
1          HH| C1232| uman   C1232
2  na| NN| 7830 | man| nnn    7830
3    NN| CC| C1233 | A1000   C1233
4         NN| C12333 | A10  C12333
5         NN| 12333 | A100   12333
```

Comment: this regex is better `df['A'].str.findall(r'(?:[a-zA-Z]?)[\d]+').str[0]`

Comment: or maybe `.str.extract(r'(\S*?\d+)')`

Comment: Yes .str.extract(r'(\S*?\d+)')  worked. I noticed that I have Some string like M-100 . str.extract solved the issue Thanks all :]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `|` are columns. This would be a way to do it but may not be the optimal one. However, it has the merit of being easy to read for a beginner.

```
import pandas as pd

NUMBERS = set([str(i) for i in range(10)])

df = pd.DataFrame([
               ['CC', 'WW', '765432' , 'yq5ma'],
               ['HH', 'C1232', 'uman'],
               ['na', 'NN', '7830' , 'man', 'nnn']
])
values = []
for i in df.index:
  for value in df.iloc[i]:
    if value and True in [c in value for c in NUMBERS]:
      values.append(value)
      break
print(values) # Outputs ['765432', 'C1232', '7830']
```